# Unable to convert multiple API response into xml in single call

Tags: karate

I am sending multiple API calls and getting their respective responses back. I am trying to convert each response into XML but it is failing with an error.

The setup:

```
        * table requestTable
            | nameTags| ageGroups| status |
            | nameTag1| ageGroup1| 200    |
            | nameTag2| ageGroup2| 200    | 
            | nameTag3| ageGroup3| 200    | 
        * def getRequest = call read('target.feature@getRequest') requestTable
        * xml transformResponse = $getRequest[*].response

Getting the following error:
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImplAccAccess (in unnamed module @0x1414800e) 
cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl (in module java.xml) because 
module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom to unnamed module @0x1414800e
```

If I do a single conversion such as: `* xml transformResponse = $getRequest[0].response` it works as expected.

Please advise.

Comment: you seem to be doing json-path on xml, which karate is not designed for. you are on your own. if you would like to report a bug, you know what to do: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I see a solution using `--add-opens` here that was reported to fix this error
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/5509